# Restrict attribute value depending on value of another attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

Consider this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="X">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction>
                        <xs:enumeration value="One"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Two"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="Y">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <!-- Choose how to restrict the value based on the value of the X attribute. -->
                    <xs:restriction base="if X=One then List1 else List2"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="List1">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Option1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Option2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="List2">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Option3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Option4"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

So for the attribute `Test/@Y`, I want to restrict the possible values based on the value of `Test/@X`. If `X` is `One`, then `Y` can must be in `List1`, otherwise, `Y` must be in `List2`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this question about co-occurrence constraints: [XSD: Define attributes based on the value of previous attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412224/xsd-define-attributes-based-on-the-value-of-previous-attribute/11413401#11413401)

Summarizing:

- Possible in XSD 1.1
- Not possible in XSD 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was tough to Google this one as it's hard to put it into simple word. Now I know co-occurence is the query I needed.